# How to send any data from Lambda function invoked by Alexa custom skill to an application running on local PC

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am building a custom skill for Amazon Eco to control a specific application on windows. My custom skill is invoking a `Lambda function` and as a response I want to send some data to application by which I can control that application. I am willing to use any Amazon services.

Here multiple user can use same skill and responses should to send to respective users application.

Will any one have any idea how can I archive it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can expose your application *publicly* using port forwarding or using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), *(it is a service where it can give you a Public URL for your local application or server)*, then let your lambda function make the request to your application via HTTP.

Also, you can have a server that listen to Alexa Skill request then make your application listen to your server using web socket.

**Single User, One Echo device**: you can access the *deviceId* of the echo device using [this method](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/tree/master#services) then assign it to the user and save it to your local database.

**Multiple User, One Echo device**: you need to make a function on how to identify each user, you can do this by asking for a username then have a secret for each user, where the secret can be renewed via an app, this can be complicated depending on your use case.

Comment: Using ngrok how do I manage multiple user running application on their PC and have Eco with same custom skill? As per my understanding ngrok is providing a public URL on which we have to request from Lambda, but here we may have multiple users. How it can be managed.

Comment: you can manage your user using a web server.

if your web server is hosted locally you can use ngrok to make it publicly available, then in your lambda function you can do some HTTP request to your local server via ngrok.

Comment: Mmmh do you mean that if my echo is in the same network than my local server, then Alexa is not able to reach my local server using an http request with local IP ? Eg : If my Echo local IP is 192.168.1.7 and my local server is on 192.168.1.9 then Echo / Alexa cannot http request 192.168.1.9 ? Or maybe I misunderstanding something.